# Is there any PayPal API that can retrieve button options from a transaction id?

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create some tools to manage our paypal account and I can't find a PayPal API that actually returns the purchase options when orders are made from PayPal buttons.

The REST APIs for sales and orders don't seem to return option names or option values.

The NVP API GetTransactionDetails only returned 2 of the 4 options I have set on the button.

Has anyone been able to retrieve this information through any API? I can see them when I look at transaction details on the PayPal site.

Comment: IPN provides that information.

Comment: Yeah, IPN provides it, but I want to get it after the fact.